# How to use hyperlink for image popup in web map based on QGIS 3.4.3?

Tags: qgis, web-mapping

I have a point shapefile layer, that I added into it a hyperlinks row. Each hyperlink is for a image, all in me dropbox.
When I identify a point, I see the selected image.
However, when I export it to web map with QGIS2WEB plugin, I see only the hyperlink not the image. When I click on the hyperlink the image is open in a different window. 
I like to see the image directly, can it be done?

Here are the steps I made:

In the layer properties I selected "Attachment" in the "Widget Type", I click on the "Use a hyperlink for document path (read-only)" and set the "Integrated Document Viewer" on Image type.

[image]

[image]

At this point I was able to create a hyperlink from the attribute table.
[image]

On QGIS the image is visible, using identify feature
[image]

As I wrote, when I use the QGIS2WEB plugin, I see only the link and not the image. 
 [image]

How can see these image directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you export your map with qgis2web as Leaflet map, you can easily adapt the popup content in the index.html as you want to.

[image]

Open the exported index.html and look for `var popupContent =` 
At this point, the popup content is defined as HTML table.

Just add another row at the bottom of the table in your popup-content definition and insert an `<img>`-Tag:

```
var popupContent = 
[...]
    <td><img src="' + (feature.properties['URL-attribute'] !== null ? Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['URL-attribute'])) : '') + '" height="100px"></td>\
[...]
```

"URL-attribute" would correspond to your attribute with the imagepath inside.

Comment: Can you add some print screen? I am not sure what do you mean. Thanks

Comment: I've edited my answer. I suggest you are using OpenLayers, right? Would it be an option using Leafleat? In my opinion it's much more user-friendly and easier to understand for beginners.

Comment: I am using  Leafleat by the QGIS2WEB plugin, I will look at what you wrote.