# QGIS Problem with displaying web-based images by Action attribute

Tags: qgis, image, popup

I have the .csv file, which includes the direct URLs to the images in the columns.
Unfortunately, I can't open them at some point.

Following this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKxbOOsWwvk&ab_channel=GISCoordinated

and the link below:

https://www.lifeingis.com/using-photos-in-qgis-projects/

I was unsuccessful, as I noticed an utter lack of reaction when clicking on my layer. Moreover I couldn't see the "Action" column in my data attribute table. I use QGIS 3.12 version.

[image]

Next I thought, that potentially my widget was wrong, as indicated in this thread:

[How to use hyperlink for image popup in web map based on QGIS 3.4.3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308540/how-to-use-hyperlink-for-image-popup-in-web-map-based-on-qgis-3-4-3/308555)

[Show images related to features in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237156/show-images-related-to-features-in-qgis)

but it didn't change after choosing the "Attachment" instead of "Text".

[image]

How can I make my image popup valid? What I am missing here?

UPDATE:

This hint

[Using Hyperlink URL in attribute table of QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217390/using-hyperlink-url-in-attribute-table-of-qgis)

also didn't work for me